# Hazlecast Find a range by a number look-up

Tags: hazelcast, querydsl

I'm new to hazle-cast, trying to implement a look up using hazle-cast. My scenario is, I have a range of numbers 1-10,10-20,20-30 ... . If I get a request with a number then I need to return the range which it belong to, for example if the request comes with number 22, then I should be returning the 20-30 range . Is it possible with hazle-cast query ? if you have done similar implementation, appreciate if you can please share .

The SQL query we execute to find this is

```
select * from table where '21' between min and max
```

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast offers the following APIs for distributed query purposes:

- Criteria API (programming interface offered by Hazelcast that is similar to the Java Persistence Query Language (JPQL))
- Distributed SQL Query (com.hazelcast.query.SqlPredicate takes the regular SQL where clause)

You can find the documentation here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#distributed-query

Here is an example of SqlPredicate:

```
public class SqlPredicateSample {

    public static class Item implements Serializable {
        String name;
        int number;

        public Item(String name, int number) {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return "Item{"
                    + "name='" + name + '\''
                    + ", number=" + number
                    + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Start the Embedded Hazelcast Cluster Member.
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        // Get a Distributed Map called "items"
        IMap<Integer, Item> items = hz.getMap("items");
        // Add some users to the Distributed Map
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            items.put(i, new Item("name" + i , i));
        }
        Predicate sqlQuery = new SqlPredicate("name = 'name22' AND number BETWEEN 20 AND 30");
        Collection<Item> objects = items.values(sqlQuery);

        System.out.println(objects);
    }
}
```

As a work-around solution, via using java.lang.Math.floorDiv(dividend, divisor) built-in function, you can calculate the key that will be stored in Hazelcast `IMap<Integer, List>` map with the corresponding number list.

```
private void workAroundSolution() {
    HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
    IMap<Integer, List> map = client.getMap("map");

    int sequence = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int key = i + 1;
        int min = i * sequence;
        int max = key * sequence;
        List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(min, max).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        map.put(i, list);
    }


    int givenValue = 22;
    int key = Math.floorDiv(givenValue, sequence);

    System.out.println("Key to look up: " + key);
    System.out.println("Range of values: " + map.get(key));
}
```